# Bizzarre error in compound statement in R?: "target of assignment expands to non-language object"

Tags: r, syntax, syntax-error, assignment-operator

I have a very strange thing happening in R.  This code gives the following error, "Error in 1 && CurrentData$phase[i] > -0.5 || PriorData$phase[MatchTimeFrames(i,  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object"

```
  return (CurrentData$phase[i-1]<-1 && CurrentData$phase[i]>-0.5 || 
         PriorData$phase[MatchTimeFrames(i, CurrentData, PriorData)-1]<-1 &&
         PriorData$phase[MatchTimeFrames(i, CurrentData, PriorData)] > -0.5 ||  
         CurrentData$phase[i]>0 ||
         PriorData$phase[MatchTimeFrames(i, CurrentData, PriorData)] >0
       )
```

If I comment out the first condition, the code runs.

```
  return (#CurrentData$phase[i-1]<-1 && CurrentData$phase[i]>-0.5 || 
         PriorData$phase[MatchTimeFrames(i, CurrentData, PriorData)-1]<-1 &&
         PriorData$phase[MatchTimeFrames(i, CurrentData, PriorData)] > -0.5 ||  
         CurrentData$phase[i]>0 ||
         PriorData$phase[MatchTimeFrames(i, CurrentData, PriorData)] >0
       )
```

If I comment out the second condition, the code runs.

```
  return (CurrentData$phase[i-1]<-1 && CurrentData$phase[i]>-0.5 || 
         #PriorData$phase[MatchTimeFrames(i, CurrentData, PriorData)-1]<-1 &&
         PriorData$phase[MatchTimeFrames(i, CurrentData, PriorData)] > -0.5 ||  
         CurrentData$phase[i]>0 ||
         PriorData$phase[MatchTimeFrames(i, CurrentData, PriorData)] >0
       )
```

Obviously, I want both conditions to run and what made it work was putting a space between the less than sign and the -1 on the second condition.

```
 return (CurrentData$phase[i-1]<-1 && CurrentData$phase[i]>-0.5 || 
         PriorData$phase[MatchTimeFrames(i, CurrentData, PriorData)-1]< -1 && PriorData$phase[MatchTimeFrames(i, CurrentData, PriorData)] > -0.5 ||  
         CurrentData$phase[i]>0 ||
         PriorData$phase[MatchTimeFrames(i, CurrentData, PriorData)] >0
       )
```

Any idea why that is happening?  It seems very strange that in this particular instance R is requiring a space between the less than sign and -1.  Notice that the first term, CurrentData$phase[i-1]<-1, has no space.

Thank you.

Comment: `<-` is assignment.  You must put a space between the `<` and `-`.

Answer (score 4):

It's because `<-` is assignment.  Here is a shorter example, which makes it more clear what is happening:

```
> x <- 1 && y <- 2
Error in 1 && y <- 2 : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Comment: Painfully obvious now.  Thank you Matthew for pointing this out.